# Count/Sum in Apache Pig

Tags: filter, group-by, apache-pig

I am a beginner with Apache Pig. There is a table with the following fields:

```
table - amount:long date:string country:string
```

Initially, my aim - to get the count of the field amount per country, monthwise. For example, this would be my required end result:

```
(Exhibit A)
201201 USA 100
201201 UK 150
201305 ITALY 200
201305 USA 120
201305 UK 20
201403 ITALY 300
```

The numbers 100,150,200,300 represent the count of amount, for each date, across all the countries.To achieve this, I wrote the following pig script. It achieves the above intended result.

```
data = ORDER table BY date ASC;

data1 = GROUP data BY (date, country);

countof_amount = FOREACH data1 GENERATE
             FLATTEN(group) AS (date, country),
             COUNT(data) AS amount_count;

countof_amount1 = order countof_amount by date ASC;
```

Now, I want to find the sum of all the counts of amount for every date across all countries e.g. from Exhibit A, I would like the following results:

```
201201 250
201305 240
201403 300
```

How should I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Removed SQL tag because this is about pig.

Comment: just group by `date` instead of `(date,country)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add last three lines it will work. I tested it locally and it works fine.

```
table = LOAD 'input.txt' using PigStorage(' ') as(amount:long,date:chararray,country:chararray);  
data = ORDER table BY date ASC;  
data1 = GROUP data BY (date,country);  
countof_amount = FOREACH data1 GENERATE 
            FLATTEN(group) AS (date, country),  
           COUNT(data.amount) AS (amount_count);  
countof_amount1 = order countof_amount by date ASC;  

mycount =  group countof_amount1 by date;  
getFinalCount = FOREACH mycount  GENERATE group as date,SUM(countof_amount1.amount_count) as total;  
dump getFinalCount;
```